# Using jQuery to find and exctract data from a "sibbling"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with between 1 and 1000 datetimepickers, it's not a fixed number of them. Now I need to set minDate and maxDate on every one, and it should compare with it's "sibbling" only.

I've tried to add an attribute named sibbling, but that's probably not correct.

Below code is what I've come up with but have problems with jQuery(this.attr("sibbling")).val ...

### This is the HTML

```
<p>
    Number 1
    <input id="startdate0" type="text" sibbling="enddate0" />
    <input id="enddate0" type="text" sibbling="startdate0" />
</p>
<p>
    Number 2
    <input id="startdate1" type="text" sibbling="enddate1" />
    <input id="enddate1" type="text" sibbling="startdate1" />
</p>
<p>
...
</p>
<p>
    Number 1000
    <input id="startdate1000" type="text" sibbling="enddate1000" />
    <input id="enddate1000" type="text" sibbling="startdate1000" />
</p>
```

### This is the Code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("input[id^='startdate']").datetimepicker({
        onShow: function(ct) {
            this.setOptions({
                // this is how you usually do: maxDate:jQuery('#enddate').val()?jQuery('#enddate').val():false
                maxDate: jQuery(this.attr("sibbling")).val() ? jQuery(this.attr("sibbling")).val() : false
            })
        }
    });
    $("input[id^='enddate']").datetimepicker({
        onShow: function(ct) {
            this.setOptions({
                // this is how you usually do: minDate:jQuery('#startdate').val()?jQuery('#startdate').val():false
                minDate: jQuery(this.attr("sibbling")).val() ? jQuery(this.attr("sibbling")).val() : false
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.next()`, `.prev()` to find next/previous sibling.

Following is a simulation:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u4hzd6dk/)

```js
function createHTML() {
  var html = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    html += '<p>' +
      'Number ' + (i + 1) +
      '<input class="startDate" id="startdate' + i + '" type="text" />' +
      '<input class="endDate" id="enddate' + i + '" type="text" />' +
      '</p><br/>';
  }
  $("#content").html(html);
}

function registerEvents() {
  $(".startDate").on("blur", function() {
    console.log($(this).next().val());
  });
  $(".endDate").on("blur", function() {
    console.log($(this).prev().val());
  });
}

createHTML();
registerEvents();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```